# Subset a dataframe based on column value in r

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have what I consider to be a big dataframe : 1 178 366 rows over 36 columns.
And I would like to subset my dataframe by selecting all the rows containing a specific column value.

Let's say my dataframe (df) looks something like this:

```
OTU   Sample_site  Abundance  Family          Genus

otu1  Water        124        Comamonadaceae  Rhodoferax
otu1  Soil         85         Comamonadaceae  Rhodoferax
otu2  Water        0          Spirosomaceae   Pseudarcicella
otu2  Soil         248        Spirosomaceae   Pseudarcicella
otu3  Water        47         Comamonadaceae  Leptothrix
.
.
.
```

I would like to select rows for which the value of the column **Family** is **Comamonadaceae** and the new dataframe (df2) to look like this:

```
OTU   Sample_site  Abundance  Family          Genus

otu1  Water        124        Comamonadaceae  Rhodoferax
otu1  Soil         85         Comamonadaceae  Rhodoferax
otu3  Water        47         Comamonadaceae  Leptothrix
.
.
.
```

I tried 2 options:

```
df2 <- df %>% dplyr::filter(Family == "Comamonadaceae")
df2 <- df[df$Family=="Comamonadaceae",]
```

But neither worked and they give me empty dataframes with only the column names. So in our example:

```
OTU   Sample_site  Abundance  Family          Genus
```

I don't even know where the error is coming from. I checked multiple times for typos but it doesn't seem to be it. Could it be the size of the dataframe? The Family column being characters?

I checked quite a few similar questions but didn't find anything that matched my problem.

Any help would be appreciated,

Sophie

Comment: Your code looks right for the filtering. Maybe there's an invisible character in your data that's causing it to not match. If you copy paste from your actual data, you can be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Dan Adams, after rechecking I noticed there was a space before each taxonomic name.

So I just added a space in my code like so:

```
df2 <- df %>% dplyr::filter(Family == " Comamonadaceae")
```

Now it works just fine and I have the dataframe of my dreams. :)